# Image not drawing from Math.random function

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

My code below is supposed to draw a picture of a rock on the canvas at random times. But the code I currently have doesn't draw anything even after many refreshes. I also could do with loop round the mathRock function so that I get constant new random rocks without having to refresh the page, but I don't know which loop to use.

My code for the rock spawn is below:

```
var num;

var rock = new Image();
        rock.src = "rock.png";

mathRock();
spawnRock();

function mathRock() {
            var x = parseInt(Math.random()* 10);
            document.getElementById("num");
            }

function spawnRock() {
            if (num == 2|| num == 4 || num == 6 || num == 8){ 
                context.drawImage(rock, 500, 450);
                } else {                    
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `mathRock` function is a no-op: It assigns to a local variable and does a DOM query, but it doesn't *do* anything with that local variable or the result of the DOM query.

`spawnRock` will only ever see `undefined` for `num`, as you've declared it but never assigned a value to it.

It might be that `mathRock` was meant to assign to `num` rather than `x`, but it's unclear what (if anything) it was meant to do with the DOM query, or where `context` in `spawnRock` is meant to come from.

Answer (score 0):

The `document.getElementById("num")` will look for an element with `id="num"`, it doesn't do anything with the global variable `num`.

To make that work, you would assign the value to the variable. For calculating the random number, use the `Math.floor` method rather than parsing the number to a number:

```
function mathRock() {
  var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  num = x;
}
```

However, you should rather return the value than using a global varible, and pass the value into the next function.

You can't use a regular loop to repeatedly change the image, you need a timer. Use the `setInterval` method for that.

```
var rock = new Image();
rock.src = "rock.png";

window.setInterval(function(){
  var num = mathRock();
  spawnRock(num);
}, 5000);

function mathRock() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
}

function spawnRock(num) {
  if (num == 2|| num == 4 || num == 6 || num == 8){ 
    context.drawImage(rock, 500, 450);
  } else {                    
  }
}
```

Comment: The `context` object can't exist until after the DOM is ready and its canvas object exist.  Also, no attempts should be made to draw the `rock` image until after it has loaded, thus a `load` handler should be added to it.

Comment: I've implemented you're code above but it still isn't drawing. javascript is relatively new and I can't figure out what could be the issue..

Comment: @JamesElmes: Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/LznarL5L/ The code uses the `window.load` event to access the canvas when it exists. Wio also have a good point about making sure that the image is loaded, but right now the interval gives plenty of time for the image to load.